# How many jetways are used in Frankfurt to deplane Boeing 747-400

Tags: air-travel, airports, aircraft, fra, boeing

How many jetways does United use on Boeing 747-400 flying into Frankfurt? We are seated in row 58 and have 1 hour 25 minutes to connect.

Comment: When I flew in to Frankfurt last year on a United 744, we didn't use a jetway at all, but deplaned using stairs and were bused to the terminal.  I think there were two sets of stairs, but I am not completely certain.

Comment: The answer to this is not a constant, but may depend on many factors. As Nate says, you might not even be using jetways at all. It depends.

Comment: This totally depends on the airline, time of day and a dice roll. No way to say certain. Sometimes they use two, sometimes just one and if you are lucky, you taxi half an hour and get bussed to the other end of the airport. There are gates in terminal 1 (which United uses) with two jet bridges.

Comment: The last time I used two jetways was in SFO to board. But due to the order in which they boarded us, only one jetway was in use at any given time (from what I can tell). So how many jetways are in use may not matter, either!

Comment: I would suggest instead asking if 1:25 is sufficient to make your connection.

Comment: Is the connection on the same airline or not plus is it considered one trip, and is it a domestic or international connection?

Comment: You overcomplicated this question, just ask whether it would be sufficient time or not as Flimzy suggested.

Comment: The reason I asked about how many jetways were used is because there is an exit right by where we're sitting in the back of the plane.  If they used that I would get off rather quickly..if not we'd be almost the last off the plane.  It's a flight from sfo to frankfurt and then on to Amsterdam.  United told me that we don't clear customs in frankfurt.  We fly in on United and fly out on Lufthansa.  What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

> The reason I asked about how many jetways were used is because there
>   is an exit right by where we're sitting in the back of the plane. If
>   they used that I would get off rather quickly

The jetbridge does not stretch all the way to the back of the airplane (irrespective of the type of aircraft) it has very limited movement.

If you were to be deplaned at the gate, the rear door would not not be opened.

If you were to be deplaned at the ramp/parking then it is possible that the rear door may be opened, but then you'd likely be bused to your destination.

On the 747, when deplaning at the gate, only one door is opened. It may be possible that two jetbridges are used (one for the first class) but this is the exception rather than the norm.